# GNU find following symbolic links and name pattern fails to execute remove (rm)

Tags: bash, shell, find, posix, gnu

I tried to remove files which might be located in symlinked directories. I recognized for certain basenames, that `find` fails with the error `No such file or directory`.

Here is what I tried. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

```
touch a_b.c.d
touch a_b.d
find -L . -type f -name '*.c.d' -exec bash -c 'rm $(basename {} .c.d).d' \;
```

This fails, too

```
touch a_b.c.d
touch a_b.d
find -L . -type f -name '*.c.d' -exec rm a_b.d \;
```

**But this works**

```
touch a_x_b.c.d
touch a_x_b.d
find -L . -type f -name '*.c.d' -exec bash -c 'rm $(basename {} .c.d).d' \;
```

or this, respectively

```
touch a_x_b.c.d
touch a_x_b.d
find -L . -type f -name '*.c.d' -exec rm a_x_b.d \;
```

Comment: basename removes not only the extension but also the path, also command may not be safe with spaces in filenames

Comment: `find -L . -type f -name '*.c.d' -exec bash -c 'for f; do echo rm "${f%.c.d}.d"; done' bash {} +` may help if it is ok remove `echo`

Comment: thanks for this quite heavy workaround.. meanwhile I figured out that this is a bug in findutils (at least in v4.6) and was fixed in v4.8.. btw. I know how basename works and simply ignored safe coding for brevity reasons

Comment: ah its `+`. actually I prefer to use `\;` when working with many files